# Chat message history pages have no title

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat

Can we have a title on it please?

It could be something like `[User]'s message history` - anything that's not `chat.meta.stackexchange.com...`!

[image]

Added [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as @James suggested - take this as a bug report/feature request - whatever you want :)

Comment: @James In chat, click the arrow next to a user's (edited) message and click 'message history' - I mean that

Comment: Ah, I see - yeah no title. Again, no bug imo - something which was not implemented - ie does not exist - can't be broken, devs just never put one there (it's not like it's scripted to be there and script is fubar).